# problem installing truffle using "npm i truffle -g"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, deprecated, truffle

I am having this problem while installing truffle for my project. I have installed visual studio and also python and node-gyp but this is not going away. Also what is this deprecated warning. Please help.

```
npm install truffle -g
```

[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46VJ.png)

Comment: Your command is wrong! The correct order is: `npm install -g truffle`. And the full related logs share with us in readable format (e.g.: pastebin.com) but not a screenshot from a part of the error log.

Comment: The command is right, -g can be placed before or after package name. Please provide the full log.

Comment: brother you can find complete logs here... https://controlc.com/478a3a97

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands: (assuming your work is in `project` directory)

```
 - cd project 
 - npm init -y 
 - npm install truffle
```

This will install truffle inside node_modules of the project directory. Now to run truffle commands:

```
npx truffle <command>
```

e.g.

```
npx truffle migrate
```